# Can OpenPyxl create custom workbook views?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

*Long intro to my question...*

While trying to automate my creation of an Excel spreadsheet to track student marks (don't like any of the mark tracking tools available to me) I created a Python program which would generate my entire mark book for the term. Because our marks for some assignments span up to four categories, some assignments have marks recorded in more than one column in my mark book.

The columns are organized by category: Knowledge, Thinking, Application, Communication. I have space for 15 assignments.

So if my first assignment is being marked on all four categories, it'd have an entry in columns B, Q, AF and AU (column A has the students' names). The next assignment would be columns in C, R, AG and AV, etc.

Seeing as Excel doesn't have a horizontal filter, I thought an alternative would be to set up 15 custom views for each page, if OpenPyxl can do that. Otherwise what I end up doing is just hiding the columns in between manually (or just scrolling through my spreadsheet to get to the column I want).

**So... is there a way using OpenPyxl to create custom workbook views?** I can't find a tutorial anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: the answer is yes, but this is a very generic question.  Please refer to this for asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, I thought I explained it well. I want to create several different custom workbook views; so for example, in one view I could see column A (student names), then columns B, Q, AF, and AU. In a second custom view, I could seee columns A, C, R, AG, and AV. So, 15 views, column A + 4 columns that are 15 columns apart.

I know I can go in and manually create them, but if OpenPyxl allows for the creation of different views (which I can then access by going to the View ribbon, selecting Custom Views, and then selecting the appropriate view), then I would rather go that route.

Comment: The answer is still yes but you'll have to work out how to do it from the OOXML specification and openpyxl source code.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to find a tutorial somewhere as I'm still wrapping my head around reading the openpyxl documentation on the readthedocs website; maybe that becomes my summer project at this point. :-)

Comment: @CambridgeCro did you figured out how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @CodeoDE, thanks for following up with me; I've put the project on hold but now that you've mentioned it, I may pick it up again... :-)